# How to Setting up CruiseControl.NET Continuous Monitoring Server with TortoiseSVN?

Tags: continuous-integration, tortoisesvn, cruisecontrol.net, visualsvn-server, cruisecontrol

I have already install Visual SVN server on my server and created repository also. I install TortoiseSVN client on my client machine . My all network computer are connected through himamchi .

I want to configure CruiseControl.NET which build repository on new checking . if build is failed then send email to all user of Visual SVN server?

Please suggest me usable link .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the [wiki](http://www.cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki) for CruiseControl.NET. It contains installation and configuration instructions.